# Magento module that filter by status and change it to another one

Tags: magento-1.9, module, backend, filter, system-configuration

i'm new on Magento. I'm trying to do a module that move the order from one status to another on a selected due date/time.

I have the following code on my Observer:

```
    $selectedStatusUnformated = Mage::getStoreConfig('expiry_options/expiry_selection/expiry_status_in');
    $selectedStatusIn = "'".$selectedStatusUnformated."'";
    $selectedStatusOut = Mage::getStoreConfig('expiry_options/expiry_selection/expiry_status_out');
    $selectedDays = Mage::getStoreConfig('expiry_options/expiry_selection/expiry_day');
    $selectedTimeUnformated = Mage::getStoreConfig('expiry_options/expiry_selection/expiry_time');
    $selectedTime = str_replace(',', ':', $selectedTimeUnformated);
    $selectedIsEnabled = Mage::getStoreConfig('expiry_options/expiry_selection/expiry_enable');

      if($selectedIsEnabled == '1'){
              $orderCollection 
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', $selectedStatusIn)
                ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
                'lt' =>  new Zend_Db_Expr("DATE_ADD('".now()."', INTERVAL -'$selectedDays $selectedTime'  DAY_SECOND)"))) 
                ->getSelect()->order('entity_id')->limit(10)
              ;

      $orders=""; 

      foreach($orderCollection->getItems() as $order){
        $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
        $orderModel->load($order['entity_id']);

        if(!$orderModel->canCancel()) 
                          continue;

        $orderModel->cancel(); 
        $orderModel->setStatus($selectedStatusOut); 
        $orderModel->save();
      }
```

But when i try to run this job it returns me:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento.local\app\code\local\Resultate\PaymentDeadline\Model\Observer.php:32 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento.local\app\code\community\Aoe\Scheduler\Model\Schedule.php(213): Resultate_PaymentDeadline_Model_Observer->cancelUnpaidOrders(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento.local\app\code\community\Aoe\Scheduler\controllers\Adminhtml\JobController.php(105): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(false) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento.local\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Aoe_Scheduler_Adminhtml_JobController->runNowAction() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento.local\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('runNow') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento.local\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) #5 C:\xampp\h in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento.local\app\code\local\Resultate\PaymentDeadline\Model\Observer.php on line 32
```

Where line 32 is `"->addFieldToFilter('status', $selectedStatusIn)"`

Comment: Please let me know, what you will get in `$selectedStatusUnformated` variable because you are appending commas(,) before and after. Due to that you are getting error.

Comment: Mage::log('Status entrada unfor: '.$selectedStatusUnformated)  returns me: processing

Comment: can you please `$orderCollection` variable?

Comment: I cannot see this variable once the error stops in `->addFieldToFilter('status', $selectedStatusIn)`

And even if i set $selectedStatusIn to 'processing' for example the error persists...

Comment: So i think you get that Error due to `addFieldToFilter created_at`.. remove that line and check

Comment: You mean this?
 
`$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('status', $selectedStatusIn)->getSelect()->order('entity_id')->limit(10) ;`

Comment: Before i changed my code this was working... But i need to change the status instead state and get some selected variables.

`public function cancelUnpaidOrders(){
    $orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
    $orderCollection
      ->addFieldToFilter('state', 'processing')
      ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
      'lt' =>  new Zend_Db_Expr("DATE_ADD('".now()."', INTERVAL -'7' DAY)"))) 
      ->getSelect()->order('entity_id')->limit(10);`

Answer (score 0):

I just put this

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
```

Working now!